# synonyms for "conceive of"

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning, difference

I am not a native speaker of English and It's become very confusing to understand the meaning of "conceive of" . To conceive means to conceptualize; but why we mostly use preposition of with conceive?

Consider this sentence :

> I conceived of a machine that would help the mechanical engineers.

replacing it with conceptualize it becomes :

> I conceptualized a machine that would help the mechanical engineers.

It looks perfectly accurate without the preposition for. Can somebody please explain its exact meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "conceive" as a transitive verb with a direct object, or as an intransitive verb, with "of".
[American Heritage Dictionary "conceive"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=conceive)

transitive

2. To form or develop in the mind: *conceive a plan to increase profits*; *conceive a passion for a new acquaintance*.
3. To apprehend mentally; understand: *couldn't conceive the meaning of that sentence.*

intransitive

1. To form or hold an idea: Ancient peoples conceived of the earth as flat.

To me, "conceive" sounds more concrete. "Conceive of" sounds more vague. I don't think there's much difference.